# how to disable the past dates on my calender(datetime picker) in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

how to disable the past dates on my calender(datetime picker) in C#.
grey out the past dates enabling only the future values

Answer (score 6):

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
```

If you want disable days before the first day of current month:

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
```

Comment: I tried this,but on my calender I want to display the current month's past dates.Only the selection should be disabled so that the end user will not be allowed to block any room for the past date...

Comment: @user2815115 I amended the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
dateTimePicker.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
```

if you want to limit future dates laso use the following code

```
dateTimePicker.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
```

It will enable only 10days from the current date.

Comment: I tried this,but on my calender I want to display the current month's past dates.Only the selection should be disabled so that the end user will not be allowed to block any room for the past date...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Now;

Comment: this will not show up the past dates on my calender.I want to ratain the past dates of the current month but selecting those dates should not be possible...