# Enable past days on datetime picker

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I'm solving a little bug of an application but I have difficulty on a DateTimePicker. In a View of the application I added a DateTimePicker that needs to allow the user to select values in the past. Strangely the object disable the old dates. How can i solve it?

I tried to use DateTimePicker from other pages that actually works as the one i need to implement. But it doesn't work.

That's the code of the page where I'm trying to implement the DateTimePicker.

````
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CambioTarga";
    ViewBag.provenienza = "CambioTarga";
    TempData["FromCambioTarga"] = true;
}


<div class="form1">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Condivise/_Anagrafica.cshtml", (RSM.BusTuristiciBO.SourceDataReference.AnagraficaCliente)ViewBag.anagrafica)

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Condivise/_DatiSocietari.cshtml", (RSM.BusTuristiciBO.SourceDataReference.Dati_Soggetti)ViewBag.dati)

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Condivise/_DettaglioPermesso.cshtml", Model)

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Condivise/_VisuraTargaRidotta.cshtml", (RSM.BusTuristiciBO.SourceDataReference.DatiVisura)ViewBag.datiVisura)



    <h4 class="colorH4">Elenco Documenti Allegati Alla Richiesta </h4>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/RichiesteWeb/Dettagli/Trasversali/_ElencoDocumenti.cshtml", (IEnumerable<RSM.BusTuristiciBO.SourceDataReference.Documento>)ViewBag.allegati)

    @if (Model.Stato == "PagamentoInValutazione")
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.Label("", "Data iniziale", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataInserimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker", @Value = Model.DataInserimento.ToShortDateString(), required = "required" }, @language = "it", type = "text" })<br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataInserimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/BTAbbonamenti/_Tariffa.cshtml", (RSM.BusTuristiciBO.SourceDataReference.Tariffa)ViewBag.Tariffa)


    <br />
    <!-- partial bottoni-->
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/RichiesteWeb/Dettagli/Trasversali/_RichiesteButtons.cshtml", Model)

    @*@if (Model.Stato != "PagamentoInValutazione")
        {
            <script>
                $('#divPagaRata').hide();
            </script>
        }
        else
        {
            <script>
                $('#btnAccetta').hide();
            </script>
        }*@

    @if (Model.Stato == "InAttesaDiPagamento")
    {
        <script>
            $('#btnAccetta').hide();
        </script>
    }
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#pnlCambioTarga").hide();
        $('#ddlTipoPagamento').val('7');
        $("#txtImporto").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#ddlTipoPagamento").prop('disabled', true);
        $('#btn_VisuraIndietro').hide();
    })
</script>```
````

Comment: Check the `MinDate` property of the picker, it may be set to `DateTime.Now` somewhere. I got my idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19050334/6877477)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Mindate  does not have anything to do with it. Cause i use the exact same code used in the other pages and here it doesn't work.

Comment: Did I get this right, you want the user can pick a date from say 19xx?

Comment: Could you post the image of your view? I guess, it can be effect by other controls.